# testing against fixtures using flask

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask

The following is my app's structure

```
run.py
setup.py
app/
  blueprints/
    __init__.py
    bp_to_test.py
    another_bp_to_test.py
    models/
      Parser.py
      one_csv.py
  static/
    fixtures/
      json/
      csv/
    json/
    csv/
  tests/
    __init__.py
    run_all.py
  __init__.py
  views.py
```

Now I want those two blueprints to run against more current data found in `json/` and `csv/`, however, I want to make a test context in which they could be tested against the fixtures of static data. The blueprints look something like this:

```
bp_to_test = Blueprint('some_name', __name__)
bp_to_test.data = Parser(p, '/path/to/current/csv')

@bp_to_test.route('/get_some_data', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def get_some_data():
  #play around with data
  return new_data
```

in my `__init__.py` found in blueprints, I register it on the app with `app.register_blueprint(bp_to_test, url_prefix='/some_prefix')`.

I want to make a 'test' route where I can test it with fixture data. How could this be done?

My test class currently looks like this:
from app import app
from flask import json

```
class TestSuite():
    def __init__(self):
        self.app = app.test_client()
        self.ctx = app.test_request_context()
        self.ctx.push()

    def run_tests(self):
        try:
            with app.test_client() as c:
                for rule in app.url_map.iter_rules():
                    if rule.rule.startswith('/test') and len(rule.arguments) == 0:
                        resp = c.get(rule.rule)
                        j = json.loads(resp.data)
        finally:
            self.ctx.pop()
```

Comment: I'm a little unclear on what exactly you want to do, but take a look at mock. When you want to replace something with something else in tests, you almost always want a mocking library. http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/